# How to take out two higher values from three values in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have three values 23, 27, 20. How do I take out 23 and 27 from these values using php? I have searched and analyzed php built-in array function which can do this but was at lost. Please help me. I am newbie.

```
$p1=23;
$p2=27;
$p3=20;

$all=array($p1,$p2,$p3);
arsort($all);
$total=$all[1]+$all[2];
print "$total";// 23, 27 then sum up together 50.
```

Comment: Do you want to take out the two highest values? OR leave the lowest value?

Comment: It seems like you're almost there. Why don't you make clear what you mean by "take out". Showing your actual and expected output would go a long way to expressing your question.

Comment: Also mention your expecting output?

Comment: @ilovecode, I want take ouy the two highest values. Expected output is the sum of the two highest values. See I have edited the question.

Comment: By your question, I wonder if your problem is that you didn't realize that array indexing begins at 0, not 1, in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `rsort()`

```
rsort($all);
$top2 = array_reverse(array_slice($all, 0, 2));// will find two highest values
print_r($top2) //Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 27 ) 
echo $total= array_sum($top2);
```

or by keys

```
echo $total= $top2[0] + $top2[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Array starts with index 0 and not 1.
So instead of

```
$total= $all[1] + $all[2];
```

your logic for addition would be

```
$total= $all[0] + $all[1];
```

Try this code

```
$p1=23;
$p2=27;
$p3=20;

$all=array($p1,$p2,$p3);
rsort($all);
echo $total= $all[0] + $all[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `asort` which sort in reverse order. 
Just try this way:

```
$p1=23;
$p2=27;
$p3=20;

$all=array($p1,$p2,$p3);

arsort($all);           //Sort the array in reverse order.

$total=$all[0]+$all[1]; // get the first and the next values of the array.
                        // after the arsort they will be the higher values
print "$total";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

You will get highest value using max(2,4,6,8,10).

You will get highest value using min(22,14,68,18,15).

Hope you got it :)

Comment: Your answer does not have a solution.